# Server request keeps loading

Tags: javascript, mongodb, monk

I am trying to make a message board which takes input and saves in database. Front-end seems fine but when i add "/messages". It's just keep loading.

> Here is my "index.js" file. I tried many solutions that i found on different sites but none of them really helped.

```
 const express = require('express');
    const cors = require('cors');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const morgan = require('morgan'); 

    const messages = require('./db/messages');

    const app = express();

    app.use(morgan('tiny'));
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(bodyParser.json()); 


    app.get('/', (req, res) => { 
        res.json({
            message: 'messsage board!'
        });
    });


    app.get('/messages', (req, res) => {
        messages.getAll().then((messages) => {
            res.json(messages);

        });
    });

    app.post('/messages', (req, res) => {

        messages.create(req.body).then((messages) => {
            res.json(message);
            res.end("Request successful");
        }).catch((error) => {
            res.status(500);
            res.json(error);
            res.end("Not working");
        });
    });

    const port = process.env.PORT || 1234;
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`listening on ${port}`);
    });
```

> And here is the code for the messages:

```
const Joi = require('joi');
const db = require('./connection'); 
const messages = db.get('messages');

const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    username: Joi.string().alphanum().required(),
    subject: Joi.string().required(),
    message: Joi.string().max(500).required(),
    imageURLL: Joi.string().uri({
        scheme: [
            /https?/
        ]
    })
});

function getAll() {
    return messages.find();
}


function create(message) {
    const result = Joi.validate(message, schema);
    if (result.error == null) {
        message.created = new Date();
    return messages.insert(message);
    } else {
        return Promise.reject(result.error);
    }
}

module.exports = {
    create,
    getAll
};
```

> And here is my package.json if that helps..

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "joi": "^14.3.1",
    "monk": "^7.1.2",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2"
  }
}
```

Thank you